# Vendor files not found, after trying to install extension

Tags: magento2

I tried to install an extension in my website. Now frontend and backend are giving "Error 500" and in ssh, command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` gives me errors:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/home/148511.cloudwaysapps.com/tnkvxgzzzd/public_html/vendor/composer/../../src/Migration/cli_commands.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/148511.cloudwaysapps.com/tnkvxgzzzd/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
PHP Warning:  require(/home/148511.cloudwaysapps.com/tnkvxgzzzd/public_html/vendor/composer/../../src/Migration/cli_commands.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/148511.cloudwaysapps.com/tnkvxgzzzd/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/148511.cloudwaysapps.com/tnkvxgzzzd/public_html/vendor/composer/../../src/Migration/cli_commands.php' (include_path='/home/148511.cloudwaysapps.com/tnkvxgzzzd/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:.:/usr/share/php') in /home/148511.cloudwaysapps.com/tnkvxgzzzd/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
```

How can I fix this and get my website back to normal?

Answer (score 2):

First of all check if the module you installed is actually in the `vendor/` folder. If this is not the case and you installed it via composer you must run `composer install` after you dit that you wanna run this command `rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/di/* pub/static/* generated/*` (just to be sure).

If that doesn't fix the problem make sure you run magento in developer mode.

Run this command `bin/magento deploy:mode:show` if you run in production mode run this command `bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Hope this helps

Comment: The strangest thing is thing is that the error is about Migration Tool, that I tried to install days ago. After that website was working ok. I guess that installing a new extensio brought problems back to surface. I tried deleting var files. Command `bin/magento deploy:mode:show` is not workign and gives the same errors I posted on question description